# sql date subquery get the last

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an error "could not be bound" while trying this SQL

```
SELECT 
    promotions.id_product, price.value
FROM 
    promotions
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 id_product, date, value
     WHERE date > promotions.date) AS price ON price.id_product = promotion.id_product
```

About the SQL... I have two tables and I need get the correct price while the promotions is running (not the last price)...

Table promotions

```
id_product  | DATE       | VALUE   | Finish_date  
1           | 2018-05-01 | 20      | 2018-06-03
1           | 2018-07-02 | 18      | 2018-08-01
```

Table prices

```
id_product  | DATE       | VALUE
1           | 2018-04-01 | 30
1           | 2018-06-02 | 25
```

Comment: "`price.id_produto = promotion.id_produto`": From your table description "`produto`" should read "`product`", I'd guess.

Comment: Ops, thanks! My sql was in portuguese... And I forgotten to translate the where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You a subquery with `join` cannot be correlated to other tables in the `from` clause.

Instead, use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT p.id_product, pr.value
FROM promotions p OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 pr.id_product, pr.date, pr.value
      FROM prices pr
      WHERE pr.id_produto = p.id_produto AND pr.date > p.date            
      ORDER BY pr.date DESC
     ) pr;
```

I added the `ORDER BY`.  Presumably, you want the "next" price after the promotion date, not an arbitrary price afterwards.